# How can I solve error "Exceeded maximum execution time" in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I found a script which I really need ([link](http://www.google.com.tr/url?q=https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/14112/in-google-spreadshets-how-can-you-loop-through-all-available-sheets-not-knowing&sa=U&ei=J5ZSU72QFq-V7AavjYDgBg&ved=0CB8QFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEqx6nmmkdEaW5KSe2Pn-QrmSI2hQ)):

```
function getTotalSum(cell) {
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length ; i++ ) {
        var sheet = sheets[i];
        var val = sheet.getRange(cell).getValue();

        if (typeof(val) == 'number') {
            sum += val;   
        }       
    }

    return sum;
}
```

but it gives an error (Exceeded maximum execution time) generally.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: A Google apps script can only run for 5 minutes, it will terminate with that error after that. Do you have very many sheets?

Comment: unfortunatly yes i have many sheets and i have to add every day one more

Comment: Then it might be hard to get around. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854573/exceeded-maximum-execution-time-in-google-apps-script) a simiar question, you might have some use of the two highest voted answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following custom function successfully up to 170 sheets:

```
function getTotalSum(startrow, startcol) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var start = new Date();   
  var numSheets = ss.getNumSheets(), sum=0;
  for(var k=1; k<numSheets; k++) {
    var data = ss.getSheets()[k].getDataRange().getValues();
    var value = data[startrow-1][startcol-1];
    if(typeof(value) == 'number') {
      sum += value;   
    }       
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Going beyond the 170, problems ariase:
[image]

Therefore I created the code below that can be used for at least 750 sheets (but not to be used as a custom function).

### Code

```
// global 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
  ss.addMenu("Sum", [{name: "Go !!", functionName: "getSum"}]);
}

function getSum() {
  // get user input
  var cell = Browser.inputBox('Enter A1 notation', 'like B21',
    Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);

  // retrieve cell reference from a sheet and get row and col index
  var aCell = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell.toString());
  var row = aCell.getRow()-1, col = aCell.getColumn()-1;

  // get number of sheets and set sum to zero
  var numSheets = ss.getNumSheets(), sum=0;

  // iterate through sheets, starting from second sheet
  for(var k=1; k<numSheets; k++) {
    // bulk load sheet at once 
    var data = ss.getSheets()[k].getDataRange().getValues();

    // get value from array
    var value = data[row][col];

    // valid value
    if(typeof(value) == 'number') {
      sum += value;   
    }       
  }

  // return value to active cell   
  ss.getActiveCell().setValue(sum);
}
```

### Explained

The custom function isn't really meant to be used this extensively. Oddly, the custom function runs well within the 5 minutes of execution time for the 170 sheets (30s). The usage of `.getDataRange().getValues()` is slightly advantageous over the `.getValue()`   (appr. 30s for 750 sheets).

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[750 sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gin9wYN_q0Hfaz9SE6LnpeuHjdrH4zaSFqYNCLc314U/edit?usp=sharing)**
Create a copy and look for the extra pieces of code I added.

Comment: Jacob Jan Tuinstra thank you very much for your help.  especially your first answer solve my problem.

Comment: @Jacop when i use first of your answer (custom function) it gives an error 'Type Error: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined (row: 7, file: "Kod")'.  this line (var value = data[startrow-1][startcol-1];) what is the wrong?