# Apps Script that automates cell background coloring from HEX/RGB Codes

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I'm creating color palettes with Google Sheets as a basis for a color reference book: You can see a **sheetproof [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pFNpdVDaA0dJK23jILEqrqIxK6g49CsAwLvQoO3OiPs/edit?usp=sharing)**. I wanted to batch fill the cells' background in Column **C** according to the HEX/RGB Codes. Manipulating a script I found elsewhere, I got this:

```
function Colors_in_RGB_from_HEX()  {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 
  for (var i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++) {
    var valRgb = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
    sheet.getRange(i, 3).setBackgroundRGB(
      parseInt(valRgb.substr(1, 2), 16),
      parseInt(valRgb.substr(3, 2), 16),
      parseInt(valRgb.substr(5, 2), 16)
    );
  }
}
```

The script works but only fills **1,096** cells out of **65,536**, due to *exceeded maximum execution time* error (6 minutes). I asked for help on Reddit, 'cause Idk anything about Apps Script: I limited to copying, correcting and doing various tests with the code above (I'm more familiar with **Excel**, but it has a limit of colors-per-sheet that strangles me).

They answered me that

> the trick, unlike Excel, is that I should never read one cell at a
> time: instead I should call *getRange* once on the whole range, then
> call *getValues* and obtain an array with the colors, finally use the
> *setBakgrounds* to set the backgrounds passing the *array* of colors
> obtained as parameters

I've been studying the answer (a brain teaser for me) for about a month, but I've to surrender in front of the evidence that I need someone to write the Apps Script for me.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. I'm sorry if we have given you the wrong idea about this community. Questions centered on programming problems are a better fit for [so]. Let me explain this. While many posts have scripts, this is not a place to ask others to write scripts or ask to teach you about programming. However, you might make this question a good fit for this site if you tell us about similar questions posted here, like https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/59683/88163,  and why they don't meet your needs, while you keep the question focused on using the web apps rather than on programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [batching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29800759/13045193) to reduce the number of API calls. In this instance, you can use `Range.getValues()`, `Range.setBackgrounds()` and `Array.map()`, like this:

```
function setFillColors() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B3:B');
  const fillColors = range.getValues()
    .map(row => row.map(color => color || null));
  range.offset(0, 1).setBackgrounds(fillColors);
}
```

See [Range.getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), [Range.setBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundscolor) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).