# Conversion from Excel to Google Spreadsheet - sum across sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm importing an Excel spreadsheet into Google Drive. Its a huge spreadsheet, and overall Google spreadsheets has converted everything, except the following:

There are a few cells with formulas like this:

```
=SUM('Mon-D:Sun-D'!$DN$209)
```

Where among the many sheets, some are named `Mon-D` and `Sun-D`. But it isn't working - instead I have the error `#REF!`

Error: Unresolved sheet name 'Mon-D:Sun-D'.

So the next thing I did was wrap the names in quotes as I thought maybe it was getting confused:

```
=SUM("'Mon-D':'Sun-D'"!$DN$209)
```

or

```
=SUM('Mon-D':'Sun-D'!$DN$209)
```

But both give me `Error: Formula parse error.` I'm not very familiar with Excel, or Google Drive - what am I doing wrong? I'm guessing I need to separate the sheet names more clearly somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe:

```
=sum('Mon-D'!$DN$209,'Tue-D'!$DN$209,'Wed-D'!$DN$209,'Thu-D'!$DN$209,'Fri-D'!$DN$209,'Sat-D'!$DN$209,'Sun-D'!$DN$209)
```

Answer (score 1):

As of September 2019, Google Sheets doesn't support **3D references** like `'Mon-D:Sun-D'!$DN$209`.

One alternative it's to replace the 3D reference by regular (or 2D ) references. In the specific case of SUM, as was shown on the previous answer, add a reference for each of the sheets.

Another alternative is to create a custom function by using Google Apps Script.

```
/**
 *
 * @param {string} reference Reference a text value, i.e. "A1"
 * @param {number} start Index base 0 of the starting sheet
 * @param {number} end  Index base 0 on the ending sheet
 * @customfunction
 */
function sum3D(reference, start, end){
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpredsheet().getSheets();
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = start; i <= end; i++){
    sum += sheets[i].getRange(reference).getValue();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Use example

```
=sum3D("DN209",1,7)
```

The above formula skips the first sheet (index 0) and sum the value of `DN209` of sheet index 1 to sheet index 7.

Related

- [In Google Spreadshets, how can you loop through all available sheets not knowing the total count?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14112/88163)