# 3D Formula Google Sheets - sum across sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I'm trying to script an equivalent to Excel 3D formula into Google sheets.
I have a workbook with numerous worksheets and a master sheet that should sum up the data.

In excel I would have used this 3D formula :

```
=SUM(Sheet1:Sheet4!A2)
```

Working with Google Sheets for just a couple of months, I have some difficulties going through this.

I tried the following found here on stackExchange:

```
function sum3D(reference, start, end){
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpredsheet().getSheets();
  var sum = 0;
  for(var i = start; i <= end; i++){
    sum += sheets[i].getRange(reference).getValue();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

But this would sum the sheets only defined by their index and would not include future sheets inserted as would Excel do.

So I would like to change this script using only optional argument `fromIndex:` to sum all values across all sheets from the chosen sheet in my workbook, as ordered by tab position.

That way, I would insert my new sheets after the from Index and would be automatically added to my sum.

Here is what I came with but it's not working and literally driving me mad...

```
function sum3D(rangeReferenceString,fromIndex){
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var sum = 0;
for(var i = fromIndex){
    sum += sheets[i].getRange(reference).getValue();
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Would you be so kind to help me find my way through this?

Comment: It's common in programming to name a range "begin" + "end" or "start" + "finish", but not to mix vocabulary. (see Kate Gregory, emotional coding)

Answer (score 0):

The `for` statement requires three parameters

- one or more expressions for iteration variables initialization
- a conditional expression
- one or more expressions to change the iteration variables

Resources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Related

- [Conversion from Excel to Google Spreadsheet - sum across sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/63023/88163)