# Add all tabs to a script with out having to manually add them to the script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am trying to make this as simple as possible for users in our office that may not know how to edit script.. right now I have the following code (see below) however I have to list out each sheet name instead id like to include all sheets in this file automatically.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  dateStamp(event);
  moveClosedCases(event);
 
}
 
function dateStamp(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log(event.source)
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  //CORE VARIABLES
  // The column you want to check if something is entered.
  var COLUMNTOCHECK = 11;
  // Where you want the date time stamp offset from the input location. [row, column]
  var DATETIMELOCATION = [0, -10];
  // Sheets you are working on
  var SHEETNAMES = ['JC', 'AU', 'AP', 'NA', 'BG', 'CE']
 
  //checks that we're on the correct sheet.
  if (SHEETNAMES.includes(s.getSheetName())) {
    //checks the column to ensure it is on the one we want to cause the date to appear.
    if (r.getColumn() === COLUMNTOCHECK) {
      var dateTimeCell = r.offset(DATETIMELOCATION[0], DATETIMELOCATION[1]);
      dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
    }
  }
}
 
 
function moveClosedCases(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  // Sheets you are working on
  var SHEETNAMES = ['JC', 'AU', 'AP', 'NA', 'BG', 'CE']
  var COLUMNTOCHECK = 2 //1 = A, 2 = B etc.
 
  if (SHEETNAMES.includes(s.getName()) && r.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK && (['Closed', 'closed', 'No Response', 'no response', 'No response'].includes(r.getValue()))) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Closed Cases");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `getSheets` method of Class Spreadsheet to get all the sheets of a spreadsheet.

Example

```
/**
 * Writes to the console the name of all the sheets of the active spreadsheet
 */
function logAllSheetsNames(){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => console.log(sheet.getName());
}
```

Related

- [In Google Spreadshets, how can you loop through all available sheets not knowing the total count?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/14112/88163)
- [Conversion from Excel to Google Spreadsheet - sum across sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/63023/88163)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets